# What causes an InternalError to be thrown by sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.initSpecial()?

Tags: java, windows, winapi

Some of our Windows users get this stack trace shortly after launching our app:

```
java.lang.InternalError: Could not bind shell folder to interface
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.initSpecial(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$300(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.getNetwork(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$400(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$10.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$10.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Observations:

- Every frame in the stack trace is something in the JDK, not in our code.
- This happens only on Windows, but we've had reports of it on both Vista and Windows 7.
- This happens with various versions of Java: 1.6.0_19, 1.6.0_21, 1.7.0_11, 1.7.0_25.
- The problem happens to only a handful of our users, but is 100% repeatable for those users. Unfortunately, we haven't been able to see anything which those users' systems have in common other than exhibiting this issue, and none of our developers has ever experienced it themselves.
- My search of Oracle's bug database turned up no bugs with the same or a similar stack trace.
- There seem to be a lot of posts on the net about this particular issue without anyone having any idea what causes it.

I'm not holding out any hope of Oracle fixing whatever the problem is, if it is indeed a JDK bug---but if we knew what triggered the bug, we could at least help our users afflicted by it. Can anyone shed light on what causes this to happen?

**Edit:** The relevant native function is this one, from [ShellFolder2.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/icedtea/jdk7/jdk/raw-file/c98afec1bf86/src/windows/native/sun/windows/ShellFolder2.cpp):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_sun_awt_shell_Win32ShellFolder2_initSpecial
    (JNIEnv* env, jobject folder, jlong desktopIShellFolder, jint folderType)
{
    // Get desktop IShellFolder interface
    IShellFolder* pDesktop = (IShellFolder*)desktopIShellFolder;
    if (pDesktop == NULL) {
        JNU_ThrowInternalError(env, "Desktop shell folder missing");
        return;
    }
    // Get special folder relative PIDL
    LPITEMIDLIST relPIDL;
    HRESULT res = fn_SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL, folderType,
        &relPIDL);
    if (res != S_OK) {
        JNU_ThrowIOException(env, "Could not get shell folder ID list");
        return;
    }
    // Set field ID for relative PIDL
    env->CallVoidMethod(folder, MID_relativePIDL, (jlong)relPIDL);
    // Get special folder IShellFolder interface
    IShellFolder* pFolder;
    res = pDesktop->BindToObject(relPIDL, NULL, IID_IShellFolder,
        (void**)&pFolder);
    if (res != S_OK) {
        JNU_ThrowInternalError(env,
            "Could not bind shell folder to interface");
        return;
    }
    // Set field ID for pIShellFolder
    env->CallVoidMethod(folder, MID_pIShellFolder, (jlong)pFolder);
}
```

In order to reach the "Could not bind" exception, it looks like `pDesktop != NULL` and `relPIDL` is retrieved successfully, but `pDesktop->BindToObject()` returns something other than `S_OK`. `pDesktop` is an [`IShellFolder*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is apparently defined in Windows's `<shellapi.h>`. Aggravatingly, Java throws away the error code returned by [`IShellFolder::BindToObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So, I guess the question reduces to: What can cause `IShellFolder::BindToObject` to fail?

**Edit 2**: Since `Win32ShellFolderManager2.getNetwork()` is what's calling the `Win32ShellFolder2` ctor at [Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:181](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/icedtea/jdk7/jdk/file/afaedb56b499/src/windows/classes/sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolderManager2.java), we can see that the last argument to `Win32ShellFolder2.initSpecial` must be `Win32ShellFolder2.NETWORK`. So, is something is wrong with the user's Network Neighborhood folder, perhaps?

Comment: Is your program dealing with `JFileChooser` at the time of the crash? Take a look at [Bug ID 4879395](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4879395). Also try running your application as Administrator in the affected installations.

Comment: We do use a `JFileChooser`, but users have reported that this happens before they do anything. It's possible that a `JFileChooser` has already been or is in the process of being constructed at the time of the exception, but we can't tell due to the exception happening on a different thread. (I saw the bug you mention when searching in regard to this problem back in 2010--the stack trace is a lot different from ours, and the property indicated for the workaround doesn't exist in Java 6 or 7.)

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No, never have. I would still like to know the answer. (Actually, I'd like Oracle to fix the bug...)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are several reports similar to yours (like [this one from jEdit](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.jedit.devel/36827), [this one from codenameone](https://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/detail?id=740)  and [this one](http://www.java-forum.org/awt-swing-javafx-swt/97055-jfilechooser-could-not-bind-shell-folder-interface.html) - in german - which seems like a `JFileChooser` bug with a stack trace very close to yours in Windows 7 and Java 6). All seem related to `JFileChooser` and/or File Browsing in one way or another.

So I would approach this in one of two ways:

Either go for the time-consuming / non speculative road and take dumps of the affected installations with tools such as [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html), [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) or [JConsole](http://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/) until you are able to isolate the root cause of the problem (which may or may not be the `JFileChooser`). If you choose that path, remember that either remote access to one of the affected installations or help from a technical savvy user is a must.

Or try to take a shortcut, assume that the problem is indeed the `JFileChooser` (as anecdotal evidence shows) and release a custom version replacing the `JFileChooser` by [FileDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html). If it runs as expected on the affected machines case is closed; else give yourself a tap on the back for trying and take "The Long and Winding Road".

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and the answer was
[java.awt.FileDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html)

If you look up VbScript solutions for "Open File Dialog", it seems that there is no COM class doing the job for most of the windows platforms